# iphone Game development

Tags: iphone, ios4, cocos2d-iphone, game-engine

I would to ask about iphone Game development

i wanaa to develop a game for iphone device , i was read many info about this topic,
As i saw there are many ways to develop game for iphone like coca2D, using unity#d or UDK and other IDE's

I wanna to now WHAT IS THE easiest way or tool to develop game for iphone and if any one know the list for all possible ways for developing game for iphone :)
any idea ??

Comment: the easiest way? Tic-Tac-Toe with 9 UIButtons.

Comment: i meent the easiest IDE for make a game

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are interested in 2D game development, I would highly recommend [cocos2d](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/).  There are plenty of tutorials, both from the developers and from third parties, and there is a thriving community on the cocos2d forums to help you along with way. If you are already familiar with Objective-C you shouldn't have a problem learning it.  An added benefit is that they recently added Mac support, so porting your iPhone cocos2d app to run on MacOS (and, by extension, to sell on the Mac App Store) is trivial.

If you are working with 3D, or if you're more interested in portability, [Unity3D](http://unity3d.com/) is a very popular option.  The only sticking point with Unity3D is the price point, which starts at $400 for iOS development and goes up from there.  If that's in your budget, it's definitely worth a look.

Answer (score 1):

No offense, but you're asking the wrong question.  What you should be asking (yourself) is, what tools are best suited for my particular game and my experience level?  For example, if you've never developed on a platform, it usually helps to create a few programs from scratch (I assume this would be with the basic SDK on the iPhone) first.  Then go over your game.  Is it 2D?  3D?  What kind of complexity is involved?  What experience do you have (if any) with any of the existing tools currently out there for your platform?  If you haven't used any of them, experiment with them first to see if you like them and if they mesh with your game's needs.  Every game has different requirements and workflows.

Once you've done some research on this topic, you will have answered your own question.  With that said, however, I've heard many good things about Unity, as well as [Corona](http://www.anscamobile.com/), which lets you build apps on the iPhone (and the iPad, too, I think) and Android devices simultaneously.

Edit: [Galaxy Engine](http://code.google.com/p/galaxyengine/) and [ShiVa 3D](http://www.stonetrip.com/) also appear to be promising engines which come with tools to aid development.  ShiVa 3D can also build games for multiple platforms, which may come in handy if you are looking to port your game.

Comment: ya ,yor are right Gemini14 read my next post please

Comment: firstly thanx Gemini14 and you are right,
I have 1 year iphone development experience and i have many ideas for entertainment apps and games too BUT i never develop a game before , i was read many posts and blogs about this and i see that there are some IDE's can help any one to get the needed app faster, 
i read to that i can develop by openGL and core animation..etc BUT this way need more time and it more harder that IDE's 
I wanaa  to develop 2D games and some entertainment apps like ibeer ,

Comment: and the Candle app. when i see these apps i think  its a FLASH apps but after that and as i read flash did not sport in iphone so i start thinking with some IDE's that maybe do this.

Comment: @Adel I double checked Corona.  It doesn't create your games in Flash, but it can be used to port your existing Flash games to iOS or Android (where it will probably generate Objective-C or Java code).  I added 2 more engine options to my answer above that you may want to check out.

Answer (score 0):

Well download XCode, trick around with apple documentation and see if it suits you.

Comment: hi Conor if you read what i posted up, iam an iphone developer from 1 year and i have a mac and all projects i did on xcode BUT i wanna to know if there other way to develop game without use openGL (use good IDE)

Comment: well if you have been at it for a year you have to have a good idea of whats going on then... I dont like Unity, its only really good if you know your gonna make back all the money (alot) ant time(even more) that you would put into it. I love OpenGL, its really easy after about a month with it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few givens:

1. Buy a Mac
2. Download Xcode
3. Buy a book on beginning Objective C (not necessarily game-specific)

If you want to eventually release your game, 1. and 2. are (almost) imperative.

Comment: hi Dave  if you read what i posted up, iam an iphone developer from 1 year and i have a mac and all projects i did on xcode BUT i wanna to know if there other way to develop game without use openGL (use good IDE)

Comment: Hi Adel. I would suggest it is ultimately worth learning to use OpenGL (you don't necessarily need to understand how it works). If you get a games book, like the one I got: http://www.amazon.co.uk/Beginning-iPhone-Games-Development-Professionals/dp/1430225998/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1296303260&sr=1-1  
it comes with sample code that you can start using without needing to understand exactly how it works.
Good luck!